Sigo sin madar Notificaciones desde APP
Buenas tengo un proyecto con dos App una manda Notificaciones Push y la otra las recibe.
La App que recibe notificacion funciona si manda la notificacion desde Firebase/Menssaging, creando una nueva campaña/Mensajes de Firebase Notifications/ le pongo titulo y texto/ despues en orientar al usuario si pungo App y selecciono la App de destino/ y en los canales de notificacion de Android pongo enviaratodos (como esta en RecibirNotificacion)
public class RecibirNotificaciones extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    super.onNewToken( token );
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("enviaratodos").addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    });
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived( remoteMessage );
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0 ) {
        String titulo  = remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo");
        String detalle  = remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle");
        mayorqueoreo (titulo, detalle);
    }

}

private void mayorqueoreo(String titulo, String detalle) {
    String id = "mensaje";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this, id );
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( id, "porrainfantil", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH  );
        notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( notificationChannel );
    }
    builder.setAutoCancel( true )
           .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
           .setContentTitle( titulo )
           .setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher )
           .setContentText( detalle )
           .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
           .setContentIntent( clicknoti() )
           .setContentInfo( "porrainfantil" );

    Random random = new Random( );
    int idNotify = random.nextInt(8000);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify( idNotify, builder.build() );
}

public PendingIntent clicknoti() {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra( "color", "rojo" );
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
}

Esto funciona bien asi.
Ahora lo quiero mandar la Notificacion desde la otra App del mismo proyecto:
Lo realizo asi:
    public class MandarNotificacion {

    public void NotificacionEnviar(String detalle, Context context) {

        RequestQueue myrequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put( "to", "/topics/enviaratodos");
            JSONObject notificacion = new JSONObject();
            notificacion.put( "titulo", "Porra Cofradia Infantil");
            notificacion.put( "detalle", detalle);
            json.put( "data", notificacion );
            String URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/porracofradiainfantil/messages:send";
            JsonObjectRequest request = new  JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST,URL,json,null, null ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                    header.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                    header.put("authorization", "Bearer ya29.74094f0d9537d.....");
                    return header;
                }
            };
            myrequest.add(request);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

En principio me sale un error 401:
 [4792] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/porracofradiainfantil/messages:send

y por supuesto no manda la notificacion.
El Bearer ya29.74094f0d9537d....., ademas de que no ejecuta nunca MAP, he sacado la clave  de generar clave de una cuenta de servicio (un json) donde pone "private_key_id"
¿Esta todo bien o como hay que hacerlo para enviar estas nuevas Notificaciones con V1 ?
Gracias
